# JPA CriteriaBuilder xpath where clause

Tags: jpa, xpath

I have a XML typed column that I would like to query on using xpath.  The column is treated as a String in our domain model.
Is there a way to build a query to do this using a JPA CriteriaBuilder?

Comment: No using the defaults that JPA provides, you should extract the column and then apply the XPATH expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jpa does not support such a thing. Check if it's possible using a native query

Comment: Thanks.  I am now trying to use a native database function.  See [new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922038/jpa-criteria-api-calling-sql-server-database-exist-function)