# JPA Criteria API calling SQL Server database exist function

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, function, jpa, criteria-api

I am building a query using the JPA's `CriteriaBuilder` to call the SQL Server `exist` function to find data based on an XML field and it is failing to run due to a `The argument 1 of the XML data type method "exist" must be a string literal.` error.

I traced the SQL generated and get the same error when I try the query in SQL Server Management Studio.  I've simplified the SQL to the following for reference

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,
     N'@P0 varchar(8000)',
     N'select id, name from mytable where xmlfield.exist(@P0)=1 order by id desc',
     'true()'
select @p1
```

The interesting thing is when I try the query by itself, it runs fine and returns the results.

```
select id, name from mytable where xmlfield.exist('true()')=1 order by id desc;
```

Any thoughts on why the generated parameterized SQL statement generated does not work?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the value passed into the "exist" function must be a string literal. The example given is trying to pass a variable into the function, but then when you're running the query by itself it works just fine because you're passing in a string literal.

For example...

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '';
DECLARE @P0 NVARCHAR(500) = 'true()';

SELECT @xml.exist(@P0) -- will not work
SELECT @xml.exist('true()') -- will work
```

For the longest time I thought this made these functions worthless because I didn't know you could use variables within the string literal. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<root><item id="1" /><item id="2"><test /></item></root>';
DECLARE @item_id INT;

SET @item_id = 1; -- "test" element does not exist
SELECT @xml.exist('/root/item[@id=sql:variable("@item_id")]/test')

SET @item_id = 2; -- "test" element does exist
SELECT @xml.exist('/root/item[@id=sql:variable("@item_id")]/test')
```